# Find mean and variance of random variable using moment generating function

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, moments, moment-generating-function

> Suppose $X \sim U(a,b)$. Find the mean and  variance of $X$.

I tried to solve the exercise by computing the moment generating function and then substitute 0 to the ts but it doesn't work. How should I solve it?

Edit:
This is what I've done so far:
$m'_x(t)$ = $\frac{be^{tb} - ae^{ta} - (b-a)(e^{tb} - e^{ta})}{(t(b-a))^2}$

if I do $m'_x(0)$ substituting $0$s to the $t$s,  I get $EX = 0$ and I don't think it's the right way to do it.

What should I do?

Comment: Could you explain how substituting zero would yield *both* a mean and a variance?

Comment: Also, maybe show us what you have done so far?

Comment: How do you deal with the fact that substituting $t=0$ in your expression yields $0$ in the denominator?

Comment: That's why I'm asking, I don't think that EX = 0 is the right answer

Comment: Are you familiar with taking limits?

Comment: yes,  do I need to take the limit?